# Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected:

Tags: c#, syntax

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Trade_Entry_Application
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notionalEntry.Focus();
        }

        private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rateType.Text == "Fixed Rate")
            {
                rateType.Text = "Floating Rate";
            }
            else
            {
                rateType.Text = "Fixed Rate";
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal floatEntryInt = Convert.ToDecimal(floatEntry.Text);
            decimal notionalEntryDec = Convert.ToDecimal(notionalEntry.Text);
            decimal output = notionalEntryDec * floatEntryInt;
            string outputstr = Convert.ToString(output).ToString();
            resultBox.Text = output.ToString();
        }

        private void notionalEntry_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal notionalEntryDec = Convert.ToDecimal(notionalEntry.Text);
            if (notionalEntry.Text.EndsWith("m"))
            {
                decimal output = notionalEntryDec * 1000000;
            }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Having problems with the code as i am getting this error
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   Trade Entry Application C:\Users\spruc\Desktop\Trade Entry Application\Trade Entry Application\Trade Entry Application\Form1.cs 71  Active
I am a newbie in c# ): what i am trying to do is replace what is in the text box when you type 1m it will replace it with 10000000 and when you type 1k it will replace it with 1000 Thanks

Comment: It tells you the exact problem and the exact location :/

Comment: @HarrySpruce if you use place the cursor on the `{` it will highlight the matching ending `}` in case you didn't know.. all opening `{` must have a matching ending `}`

Comment: You have an extra bracket in your `notionalEntry_TextChanged`. I'm going to flag this as a typographical error- don't be discouraged. In the future, the error you see "(Form1.cs 71)"- 71 is the line number. Go to line 71 and you'll hopefully see what the mistake is.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra } at the end of your `notionalEntry_TextChanged` method.

In the error message, the

> Form1.cs 71

Is telling you it thinks the problem is on line 71 in the Form1.cs file. The "end-of-file expected" is pretty self explanatory, the extra } means the definition has ended prematurely, but you've still got more text after this, which is unexpected

Comment: Thanks it worked silly me